# Oracle - Trying to create a trigger, but keep getting trigger created with compilation errors.

Tags: oracle, triggers, compilation

I am new to things related to Database. I have a homework from my school. It requires me to create a trigger for when there is an update for employee salary. The question is:

"Suppose STA has a rule stating that an employee’s salary cannot be changed by more than 20% of the original salary. Create a trigger salary_change to enforce this constraint. The trigger fires whenever  there  is an  update on salaryin employeetableand  outputs  a  suitable  error message when the rule is violated. "

The structure of the table is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sp3y.png)

Below is the code that I have made but created with compilation errors.

```
create or replace trigger salary_change
before update of emp_salary on employee
for each row
begin
if :new.emp_salary > :emp_salary * 1.2 then
raise_application_error(-20000, ('New salary for employee ' || emp_name || ' is getting more than 20% raise'));
end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use `:old` to refer to the record before the update:

```
if :new.emp_salary > :old.emp_salary * 1.2 then
    -- Here ---------^
```

Comment: May I know when I should use the ":"? In the examples given by my tutor, sometimes new.emp_salary is used, but sometimes :new.emp_salary is used. ":" is also used with "=" sometimes.

Comment: I added old.emp_salary but I am still getting trigger created with compilation errors.